# Are the following model assumptions on a data stream too restrictive?

Tags: modeling, density-function, stochastic-processes, intuition, signal-processing

Suppose that you were to model a "generic" continuous-time real-world data signal $X$ taking values in a **bounded continuum** $K\subset\mathbb{R}^d$ (e.g. the body temperature of a patient or its ECG data, in which case $K$ would be a bounded interval).

**Question:** Would you consider it restrictive or invalid to $-$ for technical reasons $-$ model $X$ as a a continuous stochastic process $X=(X_t)_{t\in I}$ such that

- *for each $t\in I$*, the random variable $X_t$ admits a *continuous probability density* $\chi_t\in C(\mathbb{R}^d)$ which is **strictly positive everywhere** on $\mathbb{R}^d$ (instead of $\chi_t$ being supported on $K$ only)?

You may have that $\chi_t$ is arbitrarily small outside of $K$ (that is,  $\sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}^d\setminus K}(\chi_t(x)) \leq \varepsilon$ for an arbitrarily small $\varepsilon > 0$), but still have to assume that

1. $X_t$ has a *continuous* density $\chi_t$ on $\mathbb{R}^d$, **and**
2. $\chi_t(x)>0$ (however small) for each $x\in\mathbb{R}^d$.

**Any opinions/guesses/intuitions on this issue are welcome.**

Comment: This is done all the time, often by assuming $X$ is multivariate Normal.  You are likely to get a variety of opinions about this.  Pay attention to the thoughtful, well-supported ones that reflect a good understanding of the purposes and interpretations of models.

Comment: Thank you, @whuber! May I on this occasion ask you whether the assumption of $X$ being multivariate normal (or a Gaussian process, in the continuous case?) is done merely for mathematical convenience, or is there some additional "naturalness" behind this assumption? (I.e. would it be considered somewhat restrictive to explicitly require $X$ to not be a Gaussian process, say in order to avoid certain symmetries exhibited by the pdf of the multivariate normal?)

Comment: In many (most?) cases it's for convenience--but we should not disparage that. An insightful, useful model can be far superior to a model that might be more accurate in how it represents the world but is otherwise difficult to understand or compute with. Good modelers make educated, reasoned approximations and assess their consequences. Your question reflects that in discussing the chance the model might assign a small probability to the complement of $K.$ A modeler who adopts a Gaussian assumption will be concerned about and (at least implicitly) consider the implication of $\varepsilon\ne0.$

Comment: Thank you very much for your insightful answer, @whuber, I really appreciate it!